# How to unwrap text using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

How to unwrap a text from a HTML tag using jQUery?

For instance, how to transform this HTML

```
<p>A <i>sentence</i> with <b>bold words</b>.</p>
```

into (i.e. remove the bold tags)

```
<p>A <i>sentence</i> with bold words.</p>
```

using only jQuery and no regex?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can do this:

```
  $("b").each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith(this.childNodes);
  });
```

Note: this preserves whatever HTML you have inside where `.text()` might transform it.

If you wanted to quite literally just strip the `<b></b>` you can use [Cheeso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48082/cheeso)'s answer a bit easier in jQuery 1.4+:

```
$("p").html(function(i,h){ return h.replace(/<b>/g,'').replace(/<\/b>/g,''); });
```

Comment: This is especially useful when removing anchor elements (or any other parent elements) from text that's not wrapped in any other elements, a case in which the unwrap method doesn't work. Though the "wrap and unwrap" method would work for what I've just described, it requires the addition and remainder of mark-up such as <span></span>.

Answer (score 7):

I've become quite fond of wrapInner first and then unwrap.

For example, if you were trying to unwrap a hyperlink

```
<a id="anId" href="#">sample text</a>
```

then you can unwrap the hyperlink via

```
$('#anId').wrapInner('<span/>');
$('#anId span').unwrap();
```

Comment: This approach still works very well in cases where you need to unwrap parts of HTML without testing for inner text() or html(). I use this method to allow users to cancel selection and highlighting of dynamically generated HTML.

Answer (score 4):

How you do it depends on the additional constraints in your situation.

There's no general way to unbold.

If the tags are always `<b>`, then you can do this

```
var h = $(elementSelector).html;
h = h.replace("<b>","");
h = h.replace("</b>","");
$(elementSelector).html(h);
```

I'm not sure why you don't like Regex.

Comment: In 1.4 you can pass a function for this approach as well: `$("p").html(function(i, h) { h = h.replace(/<b>/g,''); return h.replace(/<\/b>/g,''); });`

Comment: @Gaby - Agreed, but if someone else comes across this and wants that solution, no harm in having it.

Comment: Technically, I think a regular string.replace() uses a regex, no?  It's just that I didn't use any regex codes in that string.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('b').contents().unwrap();
```

Target the contents of the element that you've selected and unwrap them.

Answer (score 2):

To unwrap only text and nothing else you could use:

```
$("b").replaceWith($("b").text());
```

Comment: Urh, where have his <i> tags gone?

Comment: Note this isn't safe when you have other tags, if **any** HTML tag is inside `<b></b>` it will be lost.

Comment: Note: Read question aloud one more time

Comment: I did, and it says remove the bold tags, not strip everything else out, so noting that in case anyone uses this approach and gets unexpected behavior.  You forget this question along with the rest of SO is found later by people trying to solve a slightly different problem.  You're not always solving the just problem at hand, if there are side-effects, best to mention them.  No offense intended, just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think relying solely on jQuery in this case needlessly complicates things. It would be easier to use the `replace` method which accepts either a normal string or a regular expression.

Using regex is generally the way to go in this case, because you want multiple substitutions which have roughly the same pattern.