# jQuery / Regex: remove all p tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, strip

I am new to Regex and hope someone can help me with the following:

I have a long string that is saved as a variable. 
The string contains plain text and HTML tags, incl. p tags.

How can I use Regex to remove all p tags from my string including classes and IDs on the p tags but without losing the text inside ? 
The string variable can contain one, multiple or no p tags but always contains at least some text.

**Example:** 
How it looks now:

```
var str = Some awesome text with a <p class='myClass'>new paragraph</p> and more text.
```

How it should look:

```
var str = Some awesome text with a new paragraph and more text.
```

Thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this is a duplicate as I also need the classes and IDs on the p tag removed.

Comment: curious: why do you have a _paragraph_ tag in the middle of a line of text?

Comment: @ Eevee: The p tags appear when certain parts of the text are centered or right aligned.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
result = str.replace(/(<p[^>]+?>|<p>|<\/p>)/img, "");
```

updated regex

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply - that's exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: better to use the other approach, which manipulates HTML rather than slopping it around with a regex

Comment: yes, but user want's regex, so why not? go ahead!

Comment: if you need to remove just p tag, and you have only string, is it really wrong to use one regex? Jquery uses regex to find elements too, so you say that find element with regex, then create several objects, then use several methods to remove tag is better than use one regex?

Comment: This also delete the content inside the first <p> if there is more than one <p>.

Comment: Please check with: `result = "<p>Hello World</p>".replace(/(<p[\s\S]+?>|<\/p>)/g, '');`. It REMOVES the content inside the `<p>` tag which is unwanted.

Comment: Cool! Now you got my upvote :)

Answer (score 7):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2409163/18771) that's easy enough to do in jQuery.

```js
var str = "Some awesome text with a <p class='myClass'>new <b>paragraph</b></p> and more text.";

var $temp = $("<div>").html(str);
$temp.find("p").each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith(this.childNodes);
});

var output = $temp.html();

$("#original").html(str);
$("#input").text(str);
$("#output").text(output);
$("#result").html(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="original"></div>
<pre id="input"></pre>
<pre id="output"></pre>
<div id="result"></div>
```