# Stop CKEditor from automatically adding <p> in blockquote

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

In my CKEditor, I have plain text that says "my text". I set `autoParagraph: false` so the text stays as `my text` and doesn't change to `<p>my text</p>`.

When I use the blockquote plugin, however, the editor automatically surrounds my text with paragraph tags:

```
<blockquote>
  <p>my text</p>
</blockquote>
```

How can I modifty the blockquote plugin to surround my text with only blockquote tags so it will look like:

```
<blockquote>
  my text
</blockquote>
```

Here is a link to the blockquote plugin code on GitHub:

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/blockquote/plugin.js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821951/jquery-regex-remove-all-p-tags

Comment: @SvenB I can't just strip all the <p> tags since I need them if my quote is multiple paragraphs. I just don't want it to add extra tags.

Comment: Than you should make a regex for <blockquote><p> ;)

Comment: @SvenB That won't work either. If I am making multiple pre-existing paragraphs into blockquotes, the first paragraph will start, and is supposed to start with <p>. In that case it would be correct to have `<blockquote><p>`. The problem is when I convert plain text into a blockquote. Then it adds extra <p> tags. It somehow detects if it is already a paragraph and only adds <p> tags if it is not already a paragraph. I want to somehow disable that check.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the disallowedContent filter in the blockquote plugin.

disallowedContent: 'p'