# Replacing an Element with it's Contents IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to replace some "nested" classes from some HTML with javascript/jquery. I need to get rid of the spans with class="foo" and leave behind only "stuff".

```
<ul>
<li>
<span class="foo">stuff
<ul>
<li><span class="foo">stuff</span>
</li>
</ul>
</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

This works in everything but IE8 (which I must unfortunately support):

```
$(".foo").each(function () {
$(this).replaceWith(this.innerHTML);
});
```

Before someone points out that there are other similar questions, please note that I've tried several methods outlined in those questions and I think my use case differs because of the "nesting". I've tried the solutions in topics on this site and others. Some of these completely crash IE8, others just don't work.

I am aware of trying to use .empty() before replaceWith, but this doesn't help... my problem isn't performance (yet) it is getting it to even work at all.

I've also tried this:

```
$(".foo").each(function () {
    var HTMLshunt = this.innerHTML;
    $(this).after(HTMLshunt).remove();
});
```

Why the "HTMLshunt" var? I was working on the premise that maybe it wasn't working in IE8 because the "after" wasn't really going "after" .foo, but inside it... because in IE8 something happens with this one: it eliminates every .foo but leaves no contents of foo behind.

This "nesting" isn't helping. I think something else cobbled together along the way would have worked if it weren't for the nesting, but it doesn't matter because there IS this nesting. If anyone can help, please respond.

Comment: By 'leave behind only "stuff"', do you mean remove the elements inside the first span as well.

Comment: How about this -> http://jsfiddle.net/hJ8aa/

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for your reply. This also works in everything except IE8. This has the same results as my second example above, and some other variants of this I've tried: it eliminates .foo and DOESN'T leave behind "stuff". I don't understand why IE8 is not throwing an error, but is ending up treating these replaces and removes as if it can't get rid of the node without getting rid of the content...

Comment: And what version of jQuery are you using.

Comment: Something looks wrong with that markup, is your example definitely correct? Nah, I think it was my eyes playing tricks on me because of the formatting.

Comment: @adeneo I'm using jquery 1.11.0

Comment: @adeneo Your example also doesn't seem to unwrap the second `.foo` http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/v79fk/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, should be IE8 friendly (though I do believe jQuery 1.11.0 should also support IE8). If reflow is any worry then you could `cloneNode` first at the expense of some memory instead.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="foo">stuff
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span class="foo">stuff</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
var fooClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.foo'),
    fooIndex,
    foo,
    fragment;

for (fooIndex = fooClasses.length - 1; fooIndex >= 0; fooIndex -= 1) {
    fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    foo = fooClasses[fooIndex];
    while (foo.firstChild) {
        fragment.appendChild(foo.firstChild);
    }

    foo.parentNode.replaceChild(fragment, foo);
}
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/YnGbd/)

With a cloned node

```
var fooClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.foo'),
    fooIndex,
    foo,
    fragment,
    clone;

for (fooIndex = fooClasses.length - 1; fooIndex >= 0; fooIndex -= 1) {
    fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    foo = fooClasses[fooIndex];
    clone = foo.cloneNode(true);
    while (clone.firstChild) {
        fragment.appendChild(clone.firstChild);
    }

    foo.parentNode.replaceChild(fragment, foo);
}
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/pzj2s/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you are using jQuery. In that case, you should just use the [`unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) method:

> Description: Remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their place.

As an example:

```
$(".foo").each(function () {
  $(this).children().unwrap();
});
```

[jsFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/8zLZp/1/)

This fiddle uses jQuery 1.9.1, so it should function in IE8.

**EDIT**

Okay, so the problem is that `jQuery.unwrap` doesn't work when a node only contains text content.

In order to work with text content, you'll have to use a slightly different approach:

```
$(".foo").each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith(this.childNodes);
});
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3apa/1/)

Full disclosure: I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409117/how-to-unwrap-text-using-jquery) for the technique.

Comment: Haven't looked at why, but there seems something funky going on here, the second `.foo` doesn't get unwrapped. http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/5gnQP/ Just like the OP attempt. http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/wW8XQ/

Comment: Ahhh... that's because `unwrap()` doesn't work with text content, only HTML nodes. I'll go ahead an update the answer.